# ros2 interface command dosen't work

Tags: ros, ros2, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm fairly new to ros so I might be missing something obvious.

During the ros2 tutorial I need to type the command 'ros2 interface', you can see in the image below that I get an error message for that command.
After some trial and error, I found a workaround for that command but when I typed it I got a message that I should use the interface command instead.
I use ros2 eloquent.

```
~$ ros2 interface show geometry_msgs/msg/Twist.msg
usage: ros2 [-h] Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...
ros2: error: argument Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'interface' (choose from 'action', 'component', 'daemon', 'extension_points', 'extensions', 'launch', 'lifecycle', 'msg', 'multicast', 'node', 'param', 'pkg', 'run', 'security', 'service', 'srv', 'topic')

~$ ros2 msg show geometry_msgs/msg/Twist
/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2msg/verb/show.py:49: UserWarning: 'ros2 msg' is deprecated and will be removed in a future ROS release. Instead use: 'ros2 interface show geometry_msgs/msg/Twist.msg'
  "'ros2 msg' is deprecated and will be removed in a future ROS release. "
# This expresses velocity in free space broken into its linear and angular parts.

Vector3  linear
Vector3  angular
```

Is there some missing package on my pc? or something I can do to be able to use the 'ros2 interface command'

Thanks in advance

edit1: added code in text form

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337842/ros2-interface-command-dosen%27t-work/) by [sagiw2@yahoo.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/49513/sagiw2@yahoo.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-18**:
Please do not (try to) post images of code or consoles (with error text). It's all text, so copy-paste it into your question.

Review the [Support Guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support), specifically the sections about *not* posting screenshots of code or console text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Eloquent is a future release, [planned for Nov 22, 2019](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Eloquent-Elusor/). So, the code-base might still be a work in progress.

I think this is one of the [planned deprecation items in ROS2CLI](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/pull/363).

(sorry meant to add a comment - not answer)

---

Originally posted by [A.G.](https://answers.ros.org/users/49522/a.g./) with karma: 36 on 2019-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sagiw2@yahoo.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/49513/sagiw2@yahoo.com/) on 2019-11-24**:
Tested it today and it worked, thanks

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2019-11-27**:
This is correct. `ros2 interface` is only available if you are using Eloquent or later.